# could not find implicit value when i compile the sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, implicit

i have a sbt project that is configured with **`Dependencias.scala`**, **`build.sbt`**,**`plugins.sbt`**, and i have this dependecy : https://christopherdavenport.github.io/cormorant/

```
 lazy val `cormorant-core`         = "io.chrisdavenport"       %% "cormorant-core"           % Version.cormorant
  lazy val `cormorant-generic`      = "io.chrisdavenport"       %% "cormorant-generic"        % Version.cormorant
  lazy val `cormorant-parser`       = "io.chrisdavenport"       %% "cormorant-parser"         % Version.cormorant
  lazy val `cormorant-http4s`       = "io.chrisdavenport"       %% "cormorant-http4s"         % Version.cormorant
  lazy val `cormorant-refined`      = "io.chrisdavenport"       %% "cormorant-refined"        % Version.cormorant
```

and when i compile it: sbt compile, it appears this error:

```
[error] /home/javier/IdeaProjects/ERPFetcherJavs/src/main/scala/com/arkondata/bipo/utils/CSVHandler.scala:11:53: could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.LabelledGeneric.Aux[A,H]
[error]   private implicit val lr: LabelledRead[ItemData] = deriveLabelledRead
[error]                                                     ^
[error] /home/javier/IdeaProjects/ERPFetcherJavs/src/main/scala/com/arkondata/bipo/utils/CSVHandler.scala:13:54: could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.LabelledGeneric.Aux[A,H]
[error]   private implicit val lw: LabelledWrite[ItemData] = deriveLabelledWrite
[error]                                                      ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

how can i fix it??

Comment: This does not seem to be a dependency issue. The compiler is complaining because the method you're calling expects an **implicit parameter** (please read up on those yourself if you don't know what they are). If you want anyone to help you with this, I think you'll need to supply a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please show ItemData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume `ItemData` is a simple case class, for example:

```
case class ItemData(a: String)
```

Then, when running the code above, the error above reproduces. Why is that happening?

`deriveLabelledRead` is a method at `package io.chrisdavenport.cormorant.generic`, which takes 2 implicits:

```
def deriveLabelledRead[A, H <: HList](
  implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, H],
  hlw: Lazy[LabelledRead[H]])
```

After reading the [docs](https://christopherdavenport.github.io/cormorant/), we need to do bunch of imports:

```
import io.chrisdavenport.cormorant._
import io.chrisdavenport.cormorant.generic.semiauto._
import io.chrisdavenport.cormorant.parser._
import io.chrisdavenport.cormorant.implicits._
import cats.implicits._
import java.util.UUID
import java.time.Instant
```

When importing those, `deriveLabelledRead` has the implicits it needs to be created correctly.